# SF collection: house slips through 4 dimensions in earthquake, person becomes immortal during Napoleonic wars

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to identify a SF collection I read in the school library in 1972 or thereabouts.

The book had a yellow cover, about 2" thick, included a story about someone who had built a house that had slipped through 4 dimensions during an earthquake, also one about someone who had become immortal following treatment during the Napoleonic wars and was now trying to reproduce the cure

Comment: Your first story is Heinlein's "And He Built a Crooked House", the second is Kersh's "Whatever Happened to Corporal Cuckoo".  A quick check of ISFB didn't turn up an anthology with both, but you can probably find it with a more comprehensive search.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/immortal-soldier-cured-with-honey-based-salve-wounds-heals-fears-drowning and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49911/short-story-about-a-house-built-in-4-dimensions for questions on each of these stories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coincidentally, I read a story just this morning which was very similar to the second described. The treatment was in the Battle of Turin in 1537.

It is *[Whatever Happened to Corporal Cuckoo](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57439)* by Gerald Kersh.

Looking at the list of anthologies with this story, I notice a Gollancz (noted for hardbacks with yellow covers).

In this anthology ([*One Hundred Years of Science Fiction* ed. Frederik Pohl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?430574)) there is a story, *A Subway Named Mobius* which fits the first story described.

EDIT: I've just seen Organic Marble's comment and it seems that *And He Built a Crooked House* is a better match for the first story. Perhaps there were 2 anthologies?

Comment: I suspect I'm confusing two books - the 'One Hundred Years of Science Fiction' looks like one of the books I was thinking of

Comment: Both "A Subway Named Möbius" and "—And He Built a Crooked House" were included in *Fantasia Mathematica* by Clifton Fadiman, which had a yellow cover IIRC. That's probably the other book.

Comment: Sad note; Kersh died very soon after his career started with these two stories.

Comment: @David I remember it being yellow only from age, and having a a big green thing on the cover (maybe a protractor?). Still, OP's copy may have been re-bound for the library — many of my school library's paperbacks were.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for a very late answer, but in case it helps ... I remember reading this very anthology, from cover to cover, repeatedly! I believe it was [this one, entitled Time Probe and edited by Clarke](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?34919)

Comment: The OP thought he remembered an anthology containing **two** stories. Clarke's *Time Probe* contains only one of them, Heinlein's "And He Built a Crooked House", which is in [many anthologies](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58495).

Comment: However, the OP remembers a yellow cover, and the [Gollancz edition](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?293522) of *Time Probe* had a yellow cover, so maybe that's one the books he remembers.

Comment: I thought I remembered likewise. I don't have the books physically available right now, alas.